# Convert 2D array to object using map or reduce in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to convert

`[[35, "Bill"], [20, "Nancy"], [27, "Joan"]]`

to

`{"Bill": 35, "Nancy": 20, "Joan": 27}`

using the `.map()` or `.reduce()` methods?

I can convert the array using:

```js
const arr = [[35, "Bill"], [20, "Nancy"], [27, "Joan"]];

let obj = {};

for (let item of arr) {
  obj[item[1]] = item[0];
}

console.log(obj);
```

But my attempts to do this using `map` or `reduce` are failing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If supported, you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert an array of `[key, value]` pairs to an object. In this case, the pairs are `[value, key]`, so we'll need to map them first to an array of `[key, value]` pairs.

```js
const arr = [[35, "Bill"], [20, "Nancy"], [27, "Joan"]];

const obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(([v, k]) => [k, v]));

console.log(obj);
```

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of objects where each contains a single key/value. Combine them to a single object by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const arr = [[35, "Bill"], [20, "Nancy"], [27, "Joan"]];

const obj = Object.assign(...arr.map(([v, k]) => ({ [k]: v })));

console.log(obj);
```

If you need to use the object as a dictionary, a better solution would be to convert the array of tuples to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
const arr = [[35, "Bill"], [20, "Nancy"], [27, "Joan"]];

const map = new Map(arr.map(([v, k]) => [k, v]));

console.log(map.get('Bill'));
```

Comment: Thanks! Why does the key need to be bracketed (`[k]`) in the `map` return? I was doing something similar but had `...=> ({k: v})` without the brackets.

Comment: when you create an object like this { k: v }, the key name is the letter k, and not the value of `k`. To get the value, you need to use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) -  [k].

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use `reduce` - on each iteration, extract both items from the array (as the key and the value), assign the value to the appropriate key in the accumulator, and return the accumulator:

```js
const input = [[35, "Bill"], [20, "Nancy"], [27, "Joan"]];
const obj = input.reduce((a, [val, key]) => {
  a[key] = val;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map the items for new objects and assign all to a single object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var array = [[35, "Bill"], [20, "Nancy"], [27, "Joan"]],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(([v, k]) => ({ [k]: v })));
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` with `Object.assign`:

```js
let array = [[35, "Bill"], [20, "Nancy"], [27, "Joan"]];
    
let result = array.reduce((acc, [value, key]) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: value }), {});
    
console.log(result);
```