# Convert 2 Dimensional Array into Object

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm hoping for some help converting a 2D array into an object.

In my spreadsheet I have a table of names and Google Drive folder identifiers (these are just examples, not real identifiers haha) -

| Name | Identifier |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 27uXqJux5ub4xlSOJpDgozuSBXpzdaqMbz |
| Name2 | VDe67puraYNFyPNCptBkffuQcajjJLFzE |

Using <kbd>getvalues()</kbd>, I have created an array of these cells called <kbd>folderIds</kbd> (leaving out the header row).

I then have another array which contains just the names, called <kbd>names</kbd>.

```
[Name1, Name2, Name3, etc]
```

My intention is to run a loop which uses the names in the second array to retrieve the folder identifier in the first array, but I'm stuck on how to convert <kbd>folderIds</kbd> into an object so that I can use the <kbd>names</kbd> array as a key to retrieve the folder identifier. The solution needs to be dynamic as <kbd>folderIds</kbd> will grow (and possibly change) over time, so I can't just manually define the object.

Ideally I would have an object that looks like this -

```
const folderIdsObj = {

    "Name1" : "27uXqJux5ub4xlSOJpDgozuSBXpzdaqMbz",
    "Name2" : "VDe67puraYNFyPNCptBkffuQcajjJLFzE"
    etc
}
```

And I would use <kbd>folderIdsObj[names[i]]</kbd> in a loop to retrieve the relevant folder identifier.

I've been digging around all over the internet, and it looks like the solution might be to use the map method, but I've never used map before and I'm not really sure where to start. I had a go but couldn't figure out how to map folderIds[0][0] to folderIds[0][1] (for example).

There may be a much simpler solution that I've missed too, though I've tried various array methods with no success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by implementing this code...

```js
twoDArray = [["Name1","12ee1du912nc1"], ["Name2", "1231cqnisani83"]]
    
const obj = Object.fromEntries(twoDArray.map(([k, v]) => [k, v]));
    
console.log(obj);
```

more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655148/convert-2d-array-to-object-using-map-or-reduce-in-javascript)

Comment: Wow that simple huh?! Thank you so much for the quick reply, this is exactly what I need. I really appreciate it!

Comment: yes @RosieMuir please up vote the answer so that people will easily find the right solution.

Comment: I can't upvote as my old account got removed and don't have the reputation required anymore :( But I have accepted the answer. Thanks again!